# Can teamcity support the scheduling function?

Tags: teamcity, scheduler

I want Teamcity to run a build (script) every 10 minutes, is there any way to setup the scheduler in Teamcity to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, [it is very easy](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers)